# What I need to do to my EditText don't change size?

Tags: android, android-edittext

By default my EditText has next view:

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:id="@+id/search_string" android:background="@drawable/search_text_bg">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
```

When I input text to it, it changes self size and background stretches. how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some attributes you need to set:

If you want to have single line edit text then do:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

If you want to define maximum lines for edit text then do:

```
android:maxLines="3"
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    OR

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  // deprecated

    OR

    android:layout_width="50dip" // Manually assign any width you want.
```